# Flutter Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am unable to initialize Firebase on my Flutter application.  I have completed all of the steps

Below is the build.gradle file:

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        
    }
```

Also here is my app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

The google-services.json is in the correct location, see image:

[image: File Structure Screenshot]

I have run flutter clean multiple times

**Update:**

Initializing Firebas like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you call initialize app after run void main?

Comment: I initialized in the initState() of the main component

Answer (score 0):

the main function should be

```
void main()async
{
Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and you should import firebase_core plugin

`import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';`

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue.  I was using a flutter plugin, flutter_multiple_image_picker, which required me to use the xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools", and the tools:node="replace" in the AndroidManifest.xml.  This must have somehow been overriding the something in the manifest causing this issue.

Moral of the story is DON'T use this tool schema in your AndroidManifest.xml becuase is can cause some weird Android errors.